# How can I save and restore the scroll position of a Flutter ListView between app restarts?

Tags: android, listview, flutter, sharedpreferences, scroll-position

I'd like to persist the scroll location of a ListView so it is restored between app restarts.

So I guess it should be saved on disk using something like `shared_preferences` (in NSUserDefaults on iOS and SharedPreferences on Android)

Is there a builtin way (or plugin) to do that?

If I have to do it manually, when should I save the scroll position? (In a native Android app I would do it in the `onPause` Activity life-cycle method.)

I searched a lot, and I can't seem to find any post or sample code that shows how to save and restore the scroll position of a ListView.

Comment: Why not in onSaveInstanceState in Android?

Comment: what's wrong with https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences?

Comment: @Eugene There is nothing wrong with shared_preferences. I'm asking if there is a builtin way (or a plugin) that already does that.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have to do it manually, when should I save the scroll position? (In a native Android app I would do it in the onPause Activity life-cycle method.)

You can use mixin [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to detect when your app goes to background and when it comes to foreground by listening [AppLifecycleState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html)

The observable lifecycle events are:

- **paused** — The application is not currently visible to the user, not responding to user input, and running in the background. It is like `onPause()` in Android
- inactive — The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input. (only IOS)
- resumed — The application is visible and responding to user input. It is like `onPostResume()` in Android
- suspending — The application will be suspended momentarily. (only Android)

---

In example I save date instead of scroll position

```
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  SharedPreferences prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print('state = $state'); // resumed, paused, inactive, suspending
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        prefs.setString('date', DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    }
  }

  _TestPageState() {
    initPrefs();
  }

  void initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(prefs.getString('date') ?? 'no date');
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We now have out of the box support for state restoration in Flutter.
Check out `restorationId` property inside `ScrollView` widget.
Check out this link to understand how to implement restoration in Flutter.
https://dev.to/pedromassango/what-is-state-restoration-and-how-to-use-it-in-flutter-5blm

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question - usage of https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences is the best option since it utilized the native way of handling such stuff - `SharedPreferences` for Android and `NSUserDefaults` for iOs. The new way to do in Android it `PersistentBundle` which can be also used in flutter, but there is no analog for iOs. Also you may use all kinds of databases and file storages but it will be overkill in this case.

Storing scroll state always was a manual task on mobile - there is no shortcuts for that out of the box - so only handmade stuff or libraries.

You can store the whole state of your stateful widget there and then restore it as a whole.